# Oracle Forms 10g - Text_IO.Fopen(filename, 'r') - how to force this procedure to read file from the local machine instead of the Server?

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle10g

Our Oracle Forms 10g has its server side sitting in the Unix server. The application is being used in Windows platform.

We are trying to read a file by using  `Text_IO.Fopen(filename, 'r')`. The issue is that this method is picking file from the server. Is there any way by which we can force it to pick the file from the local Windows machine? Or if there is any other alternative in Oracle Forms to read the file from the local machine, kindly advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to use CLIENT_TEXT_IO from WebUtil - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/howto-textio-092797.html